# Confusion about parsing dates with odd characters

Tags: java, parsing, date

In Java 6, I have a date string that looks like

```
2011-11-28T21:00:00Z
```

How would I get a `java.util.Date` out of the above `String`, given the "T" and "Z" characters don't really mean anything?  (You can assume the timezone is the default time zone of the machine that is running this Java code).

Comment: Did you try simpledateformat?

Comment: But the Z character *does* mean something. It means that it's a [UTC time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC, The 'Z' time means zero UTC offset. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to ignore Z, do this:

```
String s ="2011-11-28T21:00:00Z";
Date d = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")).parse(s);
```

Comment: There is a double quote missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to do this (for parsing or formatting) - see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which give a case similar to yours as an example:

```
pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" 
result: 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming T and Z do not mean anything. You can remove them from T and Z from given string then you can use following code

String sampleDate = "2011-11-28 21:00:00";

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(sampleDate);
        System.out.println("Date: "+date);
```